# PHP gettext does not work

Tags: php, ubuntu, locale, gettext

Gettext simply does not work for me:

```
    putenv('LC_ALL=zh_CN.utf8');
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'zh_CN.utf8');
    bindtextdomain('messages', __DIR__.'/locale');
    textdomain('messages');
```

messages.mo location is locale/zh_CN.utf8/LC_MESSAGES.

```
$locale -a
C
en_AG
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
zh_CN.utf8
zh_SG.utf8
```

I'm on Ubuntu.

Any idea?

Comment: Is it not working in some particular way you'd like to share with us?

Comment: @Álvaro Nope. It manifests in gettext() and _() return original text instead of translated.

Comment: try: `bindtextdomain('messages', __DIR__.'/locale');`, maybe it helps. I think you need full pathes.

Comment: That's what I do, just pasted this for shorter writing. I hard-coded full path at the end. Will edit question to avoid confusion, thanks.

Comment: "you would like to share with us" lolol +1

Comment: on ubuntu you need to check wether your system supports the language. Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16395484/1059828

Answer (score 4):

Judging [this note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#91650), you are most likely missing UTF-8 bits. Those helped me with problem of “Gettext not working”.

```
$directory = dirname(__FILE__).'/locale';
$domain = 'mydomain';

$locale ="fi_FI.utf8";

//putenv("LANG=".$locale); //not needed for my tests, but people say it's useful for windows

setlocale( LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
bindtextdomain($domain, $directory);
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
```

Inside locale, there should be file structure of

```
./locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/mydomain.mo
```

or similar.

Important: If the mo file is already read by Apache,  it needs be restarted so that it can read the new file. In other words, there is some kind of caching system I don’t know about still.

Comment: I spent time solving a problem that Statusnet (http://status.net/ - it uses gettext) does not show my language. I found an answer here! 

After running 'make' (generating *.mo files), I needed to **restart Apache**. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by restarting apache.